# Can I pass parameters specific to an exe while launching it from a UWP app that has full trust capabilities?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, desktop-bridge, full-trust

In the Package.appmanifest we specify the GroupID and the parameters for launching an executable, for example - mstsc.exe. Can we also pass some parameters like mstsc /v:hostname? I have tried passing it that way but that hasn't worked. Is there a different way of doing this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FullTrustProcessLauncher API/extension can only launch EXEs that are included in the package. That EXE will receive the parameters you have specified in the manifest.

If you want to launch mstsc.exe (or any other EXE on the system outside of your package) you can do so by including a simple launcher EXE in your package that you launch via FullTrustProcessLauncher and it then takes care of launching the EXE you ultimately want to run, with the parameters of your choice.

I have a blog post with examples here (one of them actually launches mstsc.exe):
https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-2/

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan. You examples were really helpful. I had gotten to the point of being able to launch an exe but not with the right parameters, which I can do now with your examples. Thanks!!!