# Azure Communication Services - Teams Calls

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-communication-services

Hi with the new ACS will it be possible to fire an event when a call is answered and fire an event after the call has finished?

I'm wanting to capture the number of the call that has been answered and then open a program to pop up the details of the caller.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to hook to EventGrid events:

- [Call Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/communication-services-voice-video-events#microsoftcommunicationcallstarted)
- [Call Ended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/communication-services-voice-video-events#microsoftcommunicationcallended)

[image]

You can extract the phone number from `rawId` or use the new [`createIdentifierFromRawId`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/communication/communication-common/CHANGELOG.md#features-added-1) method to convert it to the correct identifier type for further usage.

See the [events reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/communication-services-voice-video-events) and the quickstart for [Azure Communication Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/handle-calling-events).

You can also listen to some events with the [Call Automation SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/voice-video-calling/call-automation-apis#in-call-events).

Comment: Thank you Rocky this is great!  Can I add ACS to a Windows Form and when the form is running I can handle the call started or ended events? thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows Forms are not supported by the ACS Calling package. At the moment, ACS supports only UWP on Windows as you can find here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/sdk-options#net

On the other hand, handling of the EventGrid events is platform-agnostic.

Comment: Thanks for this, could I make a UWP on Windows with ACS, and when a call is incoming or started, handle the event and then launch my Windows app and pass the phone number as a parameter? Thanks

Comment: It's a bit tricky but possible. See the answer and blogpost here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56062488/can-i-pass-parameters-specific-to-an-exe-while-launching-it-from-a-uwp-app-that

Comment: Thanks ROcky thats great. I have just realised that UWP cannot be run in server 2016 (we use RDS). Could we create a Windows Service with ACS or something similar which can run in the background? Thank you

Comment: You can use ACS EventGrid events (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/communication-services-voice-video-events#microsoftcommunicationcallstarted) to integrate with any platform. Here's a quickstart for SMS events - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/sms/handle-sms-events If the requirement is to run on a ws2016 machine, azure service bus could be a suitable endpoint type and here's how to integrate it with .net core https://stackoverflow.com/a/68039277/1332034